# Как подключить шрифт ProximaNova?

Tags: css

Как подключить шрифт ProximaNova?

Вот так подключаю

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    src: url('../fonts/ProximaNovaRegular.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/ProximaNovaRegular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/ProximaNovaRegular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/ProximaNovaRegular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/ProximaNovaRegular.svg#webfont') format('svg');
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: И что происходит?

Comment: Приведённый вами код при наличии соответствующих файлов успешно работает.

Answer (score 1):

Если видимых изменений не происходит, то в 99% ошибка в указании путей к папке с файлами шрифта!
банальная проверка:
1. пишем так: `src: url('fonts/ProximaNovaRegular.eot');`
2. папку fonts помещаем в ту же папку, где лежит файл css
3. наслаждаемся.